# how to plot labels up to yesterday not for current day in pine-script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

```
study("temp",overlay=true)
startDate=input(title="StartDate",type=input.time,defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2000 09:15:00 
  UTC+5:30"))
// newDay=change(time("D"))!= 0
// _year=valuewhen(newDay,year[1],0)
// _month = valuewhen(newDay, month[1], 0)
// yday = valuewhen(newDay, dayofmonth[1], 0)
// yesterdays_ts = timestamp(_year, _month, yday, 15, 30)
endDate=timestamp("UTC+5:30",year,month,dayofmonth, 15,30,00)
labelSession=input(title="Time session to analysis",type=input.session,defval="0915-1525")
inSession(sess)=> na(time(timeframe.period,sess + ":23456")) == false 
  and time >= startDate and time<= endDate 
  dayLow()=>security(syminfo.ticker,"D",low,lookahead=true)
if inSession(labelSession) and not inSession(labelSession)[1]  
   label.new(bar_index,dayLow()-20,"Hello",style=label.style_label_left,
   textalign=text.align_left,color=#d0cec2,textcolor=color.black)
```

if I run my code I am getting output like this"[out put image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd586.png)" but I want to print the label up to yesterday only how to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

```
isToday = true
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)